# Question on Stein's book thm. 5.1 (homotopical version of Cauchy's theorem)

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, homotopy-theory, uniform-continuity, cauchy-integral-formula

I have seen other questions about the same proof dealing with different issues but what I can't explain is the following: Let $F(s,t):[0,1]\times[a,b]\to\Bbb{C}$ a continuous function (specifically is a homotopy but it doesn't matter). Since $[0,1]\times[a,b]$ is compact, $F$ is uniformly continuous. Let $\epsilon>0$. In the book it says that there is a $\delta>0$ such that,
$$if\, |s_1-s_2|<\delta\,\Rightarrow \sup_{t\in[a,b]}|F(s_1,t)-F(s_2,t)|<\epsilon$$
My problem is the following; to me uniform continuity applied on $F$ would mean that we would have a $\delta$ such that, if $\sqrt{(s_1-s_2)^2+(t_1-t_2)^2}<\delta$ then $|F(s_1,t_1)-F(s_2,t_2)|<\epsilon$. In particular, I feel that uniform continuity would impose restrictions on both of the parameters, not just $s$. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: You can apply uniform continuity for points with $t_1 = t_2 = t$ and then you get exactly what is written there. The second parameters $t_1$ and $t_2$ were just put equal by hand.

Comment: I think I got what you are saying; correct me if I am wrong. For the $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that, if $\|(s_1,t_1)-(s_2,t_2)\|_2<\delta$ then $$|F(s_1,t_1)-F(s_2,t_2)|<\epsilon$$ Now, taking $t_1=t_2=t$ yields that, whenever $|s_1-s_2|<\delta$, $|F(s_1,t)-F(s_2,t)|<\epsilon$ holds, so by taking the supremum we would have $$\sup_{t\in[a,b]}|F(s_1,t)-F(s_2,t)|\leq\epsilon$$ and equality in the last inequality can be avoided by taking $\epsilon/2$ in the first place.

Comment: Exactly! I think that's how it works.